# Teams Client / Teams Room. Detect ative call or Meeting

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

My question is if there's a way to detect if the user (or room ressource) is in a meeting/call
Or as an option if there's active meeting on a teams room system.

I did not manage to get any information. I can connect with `Connect-MicrosoftTeams`
but there's no reaponse for examaple from `Get-CsCloudCallDataConnection`

Any idea how to get a feedback of an active call?

Thanks S

I already found this documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps

Comment: Currently there aren't any Powershell cmdlets for such scenarios.